# Reading data from binary file (Java)?

Tags: java, file-io, io, binary, datainputstream

For a class I'm working on, I have to create a program that writes binary data to a file (based on user input) and then reads it to the console. This is done with two separate programs, one that processes data and one that gets user input. Whenever I try to list the contents of the file, it prints the last item over and over. What's the problem with my code?

Here's the relevant part of the program that processes user input and prints to the console:

```
String song = null;

try
{
    DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(
    new FileInputStream( fileName ));

    while( read.available() > 0 )
    {
        song = process.readSong( fileName );
        System.out.println( song );
    }
}

catch( Exception e )
{
    System.out.println( "Error" );
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the program that processes data and reads it from the binary file:

```
public String readSong( String fileName )
{
    DataInputStream in = null;

    String sTitle;
    String sArtist;
    String sGenre;

    String song = null;

    try
    {
        in = new DataInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream( fileName )));

        sTitle = in.readUTF();
        sArtist = in.readUTF();
        sGenre = in.readUTF();

        song = sTitle + "\t" + sArtist + "\t" + sGenre;

        in.close();
    }

    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        System.out.println( "Error" );
    }

    return song;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data please? @Becca

Comment: I would expect the while loop in the first code snippet to be infinite, since `read` is never read from, so it should always have data remaining.

Comment: You don't need to, and shouldn't use `available()`. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataInputStream` object is never modified, because `DataInputStream in` is local to function `readSong()`.

You need to pass a reference of your `DataInputStream` object **read** in the function `readSong()`.

So the call should be `song = process.readSong( fileName , read );` and remove the local `DataInputStream in` from your function `readSong()`

Comment: It worked! For whatever reason, though, only the first song listed in the binary file is getting printed to the console. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

put while loop in readSong method then only it will read file line by line.
while loop is not  required in first method you just need to pass filename to readsong method.